# How to trim leading zeros in List & Label?

Tags: listlabel

Does anyone know if it's possible to trim irregular numbers in List & Label? I need to remove leading 00 from a number. Can't seem to find any function to solve my problem. Only trimming spaces or replacing strings.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 25, stripping arbitrary characters from strings using `Atrim$()` is supported. Until then, if you want to get rid of leading zeroes in a string, you might use something like `Str$(ToNumber(yourStringField),0,0)` where the last argument is the required precision in digits.